# After upgrading from win 7 to Win 10, getting Dev-C++ makefile.win compile error

Tags: c++, makefile, dev-c++

Dev C++ 4.9.9.2, Windows 10 v1709.  Had to increase SSD drive size, and at same time switched from windows 7 to Windows 10.

When compiling on windows 10, get the following error from the makefile.win...  [Error] ../../../../../../../Windows/winsxs/wow64_microsoft-windows-kernel32_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.24024_none_fcb71225ba71ee9e/kernel32.dll: No such file or directory

I do not have that 24024 file on my new system, how do I change the code to look for the file that I do have on my system?

This is what is showing in the makefile.win...LIBS = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc -mwindows ../../../../../../../Windows/winsxs/wow64_microsoft-windows-kernel32_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.24024_none_fcb71225ba71ee9e/kernel32.dll -m32

I am more of an Installshield developer then a C++ type.  I do not know what\where to change.  Changing the file in the Makefile.win does no good, as it gets recreated new every compile, so, where exactly is it getting the path and file name from, that I need to change?

Thanks

I understand that the entire makefile is needed...

```
# Project: InstallShield_Bootstrap
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
RES      = InstallShield_Bootstrap_private.res
OBJ      = installshield_bootstrap.o system.o cstone.o fileutil.o debug.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = installshield_bootstrap.o system.o cstone.o fileutil.o debug.o $(RES)
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc -mwindows ../../../../../../../Windows/winsxs/wow64_microsoft-windows-kernel32_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.24024_none_fcb71225ba71ee9e/kernel32.dll -m32
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
BIN      = Setup.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -m32
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -m32
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

installshield_bootstrap.o: installshield_bootstrap.cpp
    $(CPP) -c installshield_bootstrap.cpp -o installshield_bootstrap.o $(CXXFLAGS)

system.o: system.cpp
    $(CPP) -c system.cpp -o system.o $(CXXFLAGS)

cstone.o: cstone.cpp
    $(CPP) -c cstone.cpp -o cstone.o $(CXXFLAGS)

fileutil.o: fileutil.cpp
    $(CPP) -c fileutil.cpp -o fileutil.o $(CXXFLAGS)

debug.o: debug.cpp
    $(CPP) -c debug.cpp -o debug.o $(CXXFLAGS)

InstallShield_Bootstrap_private.res: InstallShield_Bootstrap_private.rc 
    $(WINDRES) -i InstallShield_Bootstrap_private.rc -F pe-i386 --input-format=rc -o InstallShield_Bootstrap_private.res -O coff
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  In this case, the `Makefile`s are probably required.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of replying in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It may be one of these:
Project > Project Options > Directories > Library Directories or Tools > Compiler Options > General. I would try either updating if you know where the file is now or removing the command and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Project\Project Options\Directories\Parameters\Linker, and point to the file that you want to use.  In this case (wanted 32 bit)...C:/Windows/SysWOW64/kernel32.dll.  All fixed now.